# gae-boilerplate and gcs client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to work with gae-boilerplate on google app engine and I want to
communicate with the cloud on local development server (for now).
I took the test app example and it runs perfectly but when trying to integrate with
gae-boilerplate it falls apart.

If I extend my class with `webapp2.request` it will work but I can't call it from *routes.py*,
when I extend it with boilerplate `BaseHandler`, I can call it but ` get a deadlineexceeded exception:

> TimeoutError: ('Request to Google Cloud Storage timed out.', DeadlineExceededError('Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: http:// localhost: 8080/_ah/gcs/yey-cloud-storage-trial/demo-testfile',))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question now that i found the solution.

It was because i was running old_dev_appserver.py in my server startup script.
GCS is only supported from the 1.8.1 and greater.